# Getting C# Request.Form in a separate class

Tags: c#, forms

I'm writing a `C#` helper to parse a `HTML` `POST` and create a signed string.  The string is used in a secondary form hidden input.  How can I access `Request.Form` fields in a static `C#` method?  `HttpWebResponse`? using `System.Web.UI.Page`?

```
public static string cyberSourceCheckoutHtml()
{
    List<string> _string = new List<string>();
    IDictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    try
    {
        if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var key in form.AllKeys)
            {
                _string.Add("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"" + key + "\" name=\"" + key + "\" value=\"" + Request.Params[key] + "\"/>\n");
                parameters.Add(key, Request.Params[key]);
            }
        }
        string sig = Corbis.Web.UI.CheckoutV2.Helpers.CybersourceSecureAcceptance.sign(parameters); 
        _string.Add("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"signature\" name=\"signature\" value=\"" + sig + "\"/>\n");
        //<form action="https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/pay" method="post"/>
        return _string.ToString(); 
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have access with `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`. `HttpContext.Current` is often used from helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- a cleaner and preferred option to get web related data into non-web related classes is to pass them as their non-web type.

e.g the Request.Form data is nothing but a NameValueCollection. so you can have the method like

```
public static string cyberSourceCheckoutHtml(NameValueCollection formData)
{
 // use formData instead of Request.Form
}
```

- option #2 is to use the Static Helper properties, provided in System.Web namespace to access the request.

  NameValueCollection formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;